# Override global header set in karate-config file for one scenario specifically

Tags: karate

I've a global header for Authorization, but there is one scenario from 89 where I would like to use wrong Authorization. I tried to set a new Authorization header in the scenario but since there is a global one, it is overridden.

Karate-config.js:

```
var accessToken = karate.callSingle('classpath:helpers/CreateToken.feature', config).authToken
  karate.configure('headers', {Authorization: 'Token ' + accessToken})
  return config;
```

Scenario for incorrect token:

```
Scenario: Request with invalid Token
        * header Authorization = 'Token ' + 'invalidToken'
        Given path '/example of path'
        When request {"example": ["37"]}
        And method Post
        Then status 401
```

Thanks in advance